# What are [meta] issues on D.O?

Tags: community-official-site

On drupal.org, what are exactly meta issues? Meta issues meaning issues that contain the word [meta] at the beginning of the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?categories=All) on drupal.org.

Issues that contain other smaller issues?

Comment: Not sure exactly why this question has close votes. If this question is off-topic, then the entire tag [tag:community-drupal-org] should be too, no?

Answer (score 4):

'meta' loosely means 'about', like the discussions on the meta site here. They are about the site, not drupal. Meta Tags are about the page, placing it in context. The [meta] issues are not about functionality, but rather about policy, code-cleanup, documentation, standards etc., rather than regular (functional) issues which are about achieving a result through code.

Comment: But unless I'm mistaken, it's also frequently used for large issues, where a meta issue primarily serves to keep track of all the small issues and share information about progress/roadblocks, as suggested in the OP.

Comment: In my understanding, that would be correct, to develop a strategic approach to several related issues. Really hard to develop a firm definition of the term. More of a concept ... :-)

Comment: Do you have any examples of meta issued about DO itself?  I have only seen the type that @Letharion mentions.

Comment: As one example: [API documentation cleanup sprint](http://drupal.org/node/1310084).